# Must the characteristic $d$ of a commutative ring $R$ contains all prime divisor of $|R|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, positive-characteristic

There is a conclusion like this:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $n=|R|$ be squarefree ($\nu_p(n)<=1$ for all primes $p$). Then its characteristic is $n$.

Now, let's say I have a commutative ring $R$ with size $2^2\cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^4$. Does its characteristic $d$ must contain as factor at least each of $\{2,3,5\}$?

I believe the logic why ring characteristic with squarefree size $n$ must contain each of $n$'s prime factor at least once still hold to ensure the minimality of characteristic.

Am I right?

Comment: For $p\mid\#R$, there is an additive subgroup of order $p$ (Cauchy) and hence $p\mid\operatorname{char}R$.

Comment: Thank you, user10354138! I suppose you mean all prime divisors $p$ of $n$.

Comment: I see. $#R$ is size of $R$, char$R$ is the characteristic of $R$. Thanks for the confirmation!